# Template10 code works on blank app, but not in an existing project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I just tried Template10 RingSegment, and it worked with a new blank app.

```
<Page
x:Class="RingSegmentExample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:RingSegmentExample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <RelativePanel>

        <controls:RingSegment 
        x:Name="MyRing" Radius="150" InnerRadius="100" StartAngle="-90" EndAngle="90"

        >
            <controls:RingSegment.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF727272"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.238"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Lime" Offset="0.59"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </controls:RingSegment.Fill>
        </controls:RingSegment>

        <Ellipse Width="25" Height="25" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith="MyRing" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="MyRing" Fill="SteelBlue"/>


    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

This was my blank app's code. This is working fine. I installed Template10 and Template10-validation the same way to my existing project with NuGet. In my existing project, even if i only add this to the page:

```
xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
```

And this with a RelativePanel in the same spot in the XAML:

```
<controls:RingSegment x:Name="MyRing" Radius="150" InnerRadius="100" StartAngle="-90" EndAngle="90" />
```

I cannot even see anything about the RingSegment in the designer, and the app is crashing at startup at this line:

```
this.InitializeComponent();
```

I did everything in the same way like in the blank app. I even tried to replace my MainPage.xaml to the working one and the problem is still the same. It doesnt show any problem in the code, and i cant see the RingSegment in the designer.

Do you have any idea about this problem? I could not find anything about this.

EDIT:

This is the error when i run it:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Template10Library.dll
'CustomSerialDeviceAccess.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Readdeo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Samples\AACustomSerialDeviceAccess\cs\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' in CustomSerialDeviceAccess.exe
```

Comment: What is the error when the app crashes?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: I have test your code in Template10 blank app, but I have not reproduced your issue. Could you show more detail about your project. Such as SDK version and emulator version.